# Entity Framework multiple projects with code first migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class library project named "Core" which defines CoreContext with properties for common classes:

```cs
public class CoreContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserContactInfo> UserContactInfos { get; set; }
    ... more common properties ...
}
```

Then I have multiple projects referencing the "Core" project and defining new Contexts inheriting CoreContext:

Project1:

```cs
public class Project1Context : CoreContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; } //object defined in Project1
}
```

Project2:

```cs
public class Project2Context : CoreContext
{
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; } //object defined in Project2
}
```

When I change something in Project1Context I create a new migration in Project1 which is OK,
but if I change something in the Core project, lets say add property `Company` to `UserContactInfo` I will have to go to Project1 and Project2 and add new migration and I will end up with migrations related to the Core project in Project1 and Project2.

My question is: Is there a way I can keep the migrations for CoreContext in the Core project and Project1Context and Project2Context migrations to their corresponding project and automatically execute all migrations related to the project, so when I start Project1 it will run its own migrations and CoreContext migrations?

As clarification, I have separate databases for Project1 and Project2 and recently Updated EF to version 6.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? if you have two separate databases, you need the changes in base datacontext in the migrations for both Project1 and Project2 anyway. It seems to me that what you are trying to do will introduce more overhead than creating migrations for both projects. Even if you can do it, you will still have to apply the base changes to both databases.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is not possible..
Just imagine if you are using model to create basic CRUD views and then changing the model. Your question is similar..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write your own sub class which inherits from `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`?

Comment: For this to work properly it would have to be combined with automatic migrations which isn't advised for production.